# Dockerfile Entrypoint Bash script run upon start, then run npm script with appendable CMD argument

Tags: bash, docker, exec

For local developer environments I'm ensuring that a mounted node_modules directory is cleared upon every startup via a /bin/sh command, which should be run before the server starts, but after the container is mounted and running.

**Desired behavior**, NPM script specified should be appended from the "CMD" config or other docker-compose or CLI source

```
/bin/sh -c "rm -rf /usr/src/app/node_modules/* && npm run start 
// OR 
/bin/sh -c "rm -rf /usr/src/app/node_modules/* && npm run production
```

I'm assuming this kind of scripted startup behavior is more common within a .sh file run as the entrypoint, but I'd like to specify the full command from the Dockerfile

**My current Dockerfile**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "rm -rf /usr/src/app/node_modules/* && npm run ${exec $@}"]
CMD [ "start" ]
```

I'm not sure how to handle the escaping of the double-quotes around "$@" within an ENTRYPOINT array.

Currently receiving this output from the container startup

```
start: 1: start: Bad substitution
```

Comment: Instead of `${exec $@}`, do `$@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend writing this startup procedure into its own shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Delete the library tree from the image; we're not going to use it.
rm -rf /usr/src/app/node_modules

# Interpret the command we're given as a specific `npm run` script.
exec npm run "$@"
```

Now you can `COPY` this script in your Dockerfile, and set the `ENTRYPOINT` to just run it.  Do not use a `sh -c` wrapper here.

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # in JSON-array syntax
CMD ["start"]
```

---

If you're going to inline `sh -c` like this, any parameters after the command to run are taken as the positional parameters `$0`, `$1`, and so on.  Normally `$0` is the script name (try adding `echo "$0"` to the sample script to see what comes out) and with your construction of `sh -c` you need to manually supply that parameter.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "rm -rf node_modules && npm run \"$1\"", "script"]
CMD ["start"]
```

These arrays use JSON syntax and the quote escaping is the same as in JSON or Javascript.